# django can't find tinymce

Tags: python, django, tinymce

I am using django 4.0.2 and django-tinymce 3.4.0 python 3.8

I am trying use tinymce as text editor by adding this line to main/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    path(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
    ....,
]
```

but is says `no module named tinymce`

i also tried  `import tinymce`

installed after activating in virtual env using `pip install django-tinymce`.

```
enter codxception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/guftaho/genv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/guftaho/genv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 124, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/guftaho/genv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 438, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/guftaho/genv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 77, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/guftaho/genv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
   return check_resolver(resolver)
File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/guftaho/genv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
   return check_method()
File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/guftaho/genv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 448, in check
   for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/guftaho/genv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
   res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/guftaho/genv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 634, in url_patterns
   patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/guftaho/genv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
   res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/guftaho/genv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 627, in urlconf_module
   return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
   return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/guftaho/guftaho/urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    path(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/guftaho/genv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tinymce.urls'
```

any sugesstions, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several files are missing from the `pip` install. Go to the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/jazzband/django-tinymce) and download the files manually from the `tinymce` directory. You can copy that to your `site-packages` directory in your virtual environment.

I just opened an issue about this myself.
https://github.com/jazzband/django-tinymce/issues/400